# Moving laravel 5.3 from local to live

Tags: laravel

What files do I need to change to get it running on live?

Right now this is my structure:

`website.com/barber_base`

In barber_base I have all the laravel files except public.

`website.com/public_html/barber`

In barber I have only the public content.

I searched on stack but I can't find a explanation for laravel 5+.

**EDIT**

I edited server.php in barber_base from :

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'public/'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'public/index.php';
```

to

```
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'../public_html/barber/'.$uri)) {
    return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'../public_html/barber/index.php';
```

But it is not working. I get a 500 error.

Comment: got any errors ???

Comment: @MehulKuriya see my edit.

Comment: index.php file is in public/index.php please move  it to the root and try

Comment: My index file is currently in public_html/barber/index.php. This is correct right?

Comment: your laravel version is 5.0??

Comment: My laravel version is 5.3

Comment: please check your .htaccess  it should be in root directory instead of public

Comment: I searched on stackoverflow and everyone says you move the public folder in public_html every file included.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change in below files

**\config\app.php**

```
'url' => 'http://localhost:8888',
```

**\config\session.php**

```
'domain' => null, // default will be null but sometimes session creates problem. If So then need to change in this section also.
```

Comment: @JustinTime give that path where your laravel root file like `.env` place.